# JPA: Differences between JQL and SQL

Tags: java, sql, database, jpa, jql

I need just an answer to a very specific question:

For example:

`Customer c =(Customer) manager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Customer c").getResultList().get(0);`

This code works because of the use of the Java Persistence Query Language.

`Customer c = (Customer) manager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM Customer LIMIT 1").getSingleResult();`

Using similar code and a native query casting to a `Customer` won't work, a `ClassCastException` will be raised.

That leads to the question:
**Is it possible to create objects as results from a *native query* using SQL?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can, take a look at the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String,java.lang.Class%29) for createNativeQuery (the one with 2 params; Im having trouble with the link)

just pass the class you want into the createNativeQuery call....

Answer (score 1):

I obviously haven't seen that one. It seems to be a much more convenient way than learning JQL.

But there's another issue that might be a potential pitfall: In some cases you need to enter field names in upper case letters.

> I can't be sure, but you could be
>   running into a case sensitivity issue
>   which is quite common when using
>   native queries. JPA defaults field
>   names to upper case, and if you are
>   using a database that may return
>   fieldnames as lower case, because Java
>   string comparisons are case sensitive
>   the field might not be found. This
>   will cause the resultset to return
>   null when it looks for the value for
>   "ID".

Quoted from [Oracle Forums - primary key detected to be null, but it isn't](http://kr.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=612380)

Thanks for your quick answer.

Comment: you should ask this as a separate question.

Comment: This is nota question, just a piece of additional information because as soon as I had one problem solved, I ran into the next one... anyway